# How to make new partitions on a laptop that runs Rapid Drive with a 1TB HD and 32GB SSD?

Tags: partitioning

I have a lenovo y480 with a 32GB solid state drive and a 1000GB normal HD. However, I am unable to make new partitions on the HD as the Rapid Drive tool has merged the hard drives. I only have a C partition and a D partition now. Would like to make atleast 2 more.
How do i solve this?